# How to block few ip address and allow few ip address in particular country in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I tried to block IP address from a particular country and allow some IP address in the same country (allow few IP and block few Ip in the same country). and I want to block another 2 countries IP address.

how to write code in .htaccess file.
I got some idea from this link. but it's not working on my site.if anyone knows please suggest me.
http://blamcast.net/articles/block-bots-hotlinking-ban-ip-htaccess

for ex:
I added below code in htaccess file to block 2 IP address. but it's not blocking those IP address.

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.168.44.201
deny from 224.39.163.12
allow from all
```

Comment: Have you enabled the usage of htaccess in your apache config? Do you have `AllowOverride All` in your vhost?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson ya. I enabled usage of access.